# How to avoid having to recreate objects over and over?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am creating an app that lets musicians practice the fingering of their instrument. I have a class entitled "Note" that creates new notes to be used, and I have a class called "Scales" that organizes the notes into scales that lets them be fingered. However, whenever I want to make a new scale I have to declare the same notes over and over again. Is there a way to create a function that creates all of the notes for infinite use?

Creating new Notes and assigning name and fingering:

`Note *Bb = [[Note alloc]init];
Bb.noteName = @"Bb";
[Bb setFingering:0 :button1 :button2 :button3 :button4];`

Creating a new scale:

```
Scale *Bb_major = [[Scale alloc]init];
[Bb_major makeScale:Bb :C :D :Eb :F :G :A];
```

Declaration of makeScale:

`-(void)makeScale:(NSObject*)note1 :(NSObject*)note2 :(NSObject*)note3 :(NSObject*)note4 :(NSObject*)note5 :(NSObject*)note6 :(NSObject*)note7;`

Thanks.

Comment: And recommend changing that to `makeScaleWithNotes:` that takes an `NSArray*` of notes;  lots of bare arguments like that are really annoying, hard to read, and harder to refactor.   For example, the moment you decide that you need to support alternate tunings that do not use a 7 note scale, you're hosed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add static method in Note:

```
+ (Note *) noteBb
{
    static Note *Bb = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken = 0;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Bb = [[Note alloc]init];
        Bb.noteName = @"Bb";
       [Bb setFingering:0 :button1 :button2 :button3 :button4];    
    });
    return Bb;
}
```